# not able to set background to full section

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a section using HTML5 + jquery. i set a image as background to that section, but image is not setting to full section.It leaves some 2px space at all 4 sides inside the section.
My code is;

```
<div id="container" data-role="page">
    <div style="..." data-role="header"><h>HOME</h></div>
    <section id="mainsection">
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainsection
{
    height:40px;
    width:40%;
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-top:5%;
    float:left;
    background: url("images/pic99.png") no-repeat;
    background-size : cover;
    background-color:red;
}
```

I have used background-size property in % too,which is also not working. And i'm using jquery-1.10.2.js, jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js, jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css.
Background-color property is setting exactly to 100% & only i have this problem when using image in background property.

Comment: Check using tool like Firebug, if your background image has any padding or margin values (probably inherited), it might be the trick. Also, please make sure, your section fills all the screen.

Comment: try removing no-repeat

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/vNaqR/24/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#mainsection
{
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eUNKu/1/)**

Set `margin` and `padding` are `0px`. 
Please try this...

```
#mainsection{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
*{
padding:0px;
margin :0px; 
}
```